# looping with for ( in ) on Javascript does not match ColdFusion

Tags: javascript, arrays, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016

In ColdFusion, I can do this

```
<cfscript>
  favorites = [{"broker_label":"spectra"}]; 

  for (afav in favorites)   {
    writedump(afav);
  }
</cfscript>
```

And I get each row in the array.

If I try this in Javascript

```
favorites = [{"broker_label":"spectra"}];   

for (var afav in favorites) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(afav));
}
```

And all I get is 0, or to be exact. `"\"0\""`

What is going on?

Comment: `for ... in ...` loops over the keys of your items. `for ... of ...` loops over the values

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, that was typo. Fixed it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to iterator over the values of an array you can use [`for…of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or [`array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
favorites = [{"broker_label":"spectra"}]; 

for (let fav of favorites)   {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(fav));
}

// or:

favorites.forEach(elem => console.log(JSON.stringify(elem)))
```

`for…in` iterates over the properties which in the case of arrays is the indexes. Note that using `for…in` with arrays is discouraged when order is important:

From *https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in*:

> Note: for...in should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index order is important.

Answer (score 0):

ColdFusion returns each element in the array.

Javascript return the index of the element in the array. To get similar results, I had to

```
 for (var afav in favorites)    {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(favorites[afav]));
 }
```